# Remaining time does not become 0 in CountDownTimer Android

Tags: android

I am using a countdown timer in android. The timer should become 0 while it finished. Most of the time it works fine but some times it stopped few second before.

[image]

Here the code i used ..

```
   new CountDownTimer(SignupOrLoginActivity.otpDuration, 500) {

        int count =0;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Test Timer "+count+" "+SignupOrLoginActivity.otpDuration +" "+millisUntilFinished );
            mTimerTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(new Date(millisUntilFinished)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //mTimerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mResendOTPButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this class and works fine to display OTP time, it runs for 2 minutes with an interval of 1 seconds. Here is my class

```
new CountDownTimer(1000 * 120, 1000)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;

            countdownTV.setText(minutes + ":" + " " + seconds + " " + "left");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            countdownTV.setText("done");
        }
    }.start();
```